# app has stopped (runtime error) onclick

Tags: android, android-studio

I added a button to change text (in the array) when clicking on it.

When the current index reaches the length of the array, I need a toast message to pop up, and also not to update the current index.

But there are errors. Please help me!

This my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (currentIndex == 22) {
        Toast.makeText(azka.this, "YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    currentIndex++;
    simpleTextSwitcher.setText(strings[currentIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: Please format indent of the code

Comment: Please post your log of crash here also

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize `currentIndex`? You're using **`currentIndex++;`** but you never initialize it unless it is your position.

And you're using `return` inside an `if` when you're using a void from `onClick`. 
If you want to do something like this try something like this:

And change first parameter of Toast to `v.getContext()`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (currentIndex == 22) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //Code if is not equals to 22
    }
}
```